# How to pass data from razor into a viewbag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have webgrid with data, each row has "add" button
how is it possible to add data from this row into viewbag or list that i can send to controller ?

Comment: I think, your approach here mentioned is not correct. You could call a js function on clicking the add button. Pass `this` as parameter to js function and access the control values in js function and finally pass values in the Controller Action Method.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to do this. One of them is using [Formcollection](http://stack247.wordpress.com/2011/03/20/get-forms-post-values-in-asp-net-mvc-with-formcollection/)

```
<input type="input" name="myData[1]"/>
<input type="input" name="myData[2]"/>
```

and on controller you can do:

```
[httpPost]    
public ActionResult myController(FormCollection form)
{
    var myData1 = form["myData[1]"];    
    var myData2 = form["myData[2]"];    
}
```